# Any built in method in behave that can parse a scenario given as text input and gives me back the list of steps

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

I have a unique problem where I need to list down all the steps in a behave scenario. I need to achieve this for hundreds of scenarios. My actual requirement is to convert a behave scenario into a manual test case so each step in a scenario can be a manual step ( I need to achieve this in the right way)

I have tried by creating `environemnt.py` file and added `after_step(context, step)` function, but this way is costly for me

So the input should be like

```
Scenario: My sample scenario
   Given My Step A
   When My Step B
   Then My Step C
```

Output must be a list like

```
['My Step A', 'My Step B', 'My Step C']
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you want to convert each step into a standalone feature, so you can run it with behave? Or do you want to convert the scenarios into another type of test, so they can be run outside of behave? Also, why is using the after_step() costly? I would either run all tests, and extract the feature / scenario / step at each step (maybe appending to a csv), or use something like beautiful soup to serialise & split the feature files as if they were strings.

Comment: _do you want to convert the scenarios into another type of test_ yes @geonaut, _why is using the after_step() costly?_ because am getting scenario details from an API, so if I have to run as behave, I need to build the feature file first and then save it and run to extract steps

Comment: I've never used behave, but there is a "--dry-run" option that might get you the output you want.

Comment: @NathanielC `--dry-run` won't include hooks, so it's not helping, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

POTENTIAL SOLUTIONS:

- Provide your own Formatter that generates the output you need and writes it to a file (or many files). The execution of "behave -f my_formatter --dry-run ..." will generate the desired information
- Use Behave's Gherkin parser and your own script to parse all feature files, then process the created model elements and write the desired output to a file(s)